# Chrome bug on button animation

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a small problem on a Wordpress site, I had to make an animation to go from the left to the right for buttons. So I use "linear-gradient", the problem is that, on Chrome ONLY, there are times (not on all buttons (?????)) a small line of color to the right or left of the button (sometimes you only see it when you hover the mouse)

Here is the code of one of the buttons that bug for example on the site :

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    padding: 12px 35px;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(50%, #515050), color-stop(50%, #ddc39f));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #515050 50%, #ddc39f 50%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #515050 50%, #ddc39f 50%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #515050 50%, #ddc39f 50%);
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position: left bottom;
}

a:hover {
    background-position: -100% 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">En savoir plus</a>
```

Here, you can see it don't bug for some reason, but in the website (when I hover it) :

[Chrome button bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQsvg.png)

So, I tried to do the animation an other way, with pseudo element, like that :

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 500;
    background-color: #ddc39f;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    padding: 8px 20px 8px 11px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    position: relative;
}

a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: #515050;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 100%;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    z-index: -1;
}

a:hover {
    background: transparent;
}

a:hover:after {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">En savoir plus</a>
```

But the problem of this animation is that the background must pass transparent, otherwise the animation (the pseudo element) cannot be shown.

So I ask you if possible, is there a way to debug the first solution, the one that only bugs on chrome or is there a way to reproduce exactly the same effect as the first one with pseudo element? Knowing that I can't add text in the  because I'm on a WordPress and that would complicate everything for not much.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who one day have the same problem. Apparently the problem is with the display, try putting :

```
display: inline-table;
```

and it should do the trick.